# Error C2084 Function already has a body

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I've seen this all over the site and still nothing has been able to fix my problem. this is the only error I have and I have no idea how to fix this. I've tried commenting out different sections of the code just to see what happens and still nothing but errors. What is going on?

Her is the build error as well

error C2084: function 'HeroProfile::HeroProfile(void)' already has a body

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "HeroProfile.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;
int race;
double weight;

    cout << "Enter your Hero's name:";
cin>> name;
cout << "Enter your Hero's Race (1:Elf 2:Human 3 Dwarf)";
cin >> race;
cout << "Enters your Hero's weight ( in pounds):";
cin >> weight;

HeroProfile Hero_1(name, race, weight);

cout << endl << "hero's Name: " << Hero_1.getName() << endl <<
    "Race: " << Hero_1.getRace() << endl <<
    "Weight:" << Hero_1.getWeight() << endl;

cout << endl;

cout << "Enter your Hero's Name:";
cin >> name;
cout << "Enter your Race (1:Elf 2:Human 3 Dwarf)";
cin >> race;
cout <<"Enter your Hero's weight (in pounds)";
cin >> weight;

HeroProfile Hero_2(name, race, weight);

Hero_2.setName(name);
Hero_2.setRace(race);
Hero_2.setWeight(weight);

cout << endl << "Hero's Name: " << Hero_2.getName() << endl <<
    "Race: " << Hero_2.getRace() << endl << "Weight: " << Hero_2.getWeight() <<     endl;

return 0;
}
```

The header File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef HeroProfiel_H 
#define HeroProfile_H

class HeroProfile 
{

public:
    //default constructor
    HeroProfile();

    //overlaod constructor
    HeroProfile(string, int, double);

    //destructor
    ~HeroProfile();

    //Accesor functions
    string getName() const;
        // get name - returns name of patient

    int getRace() const;
        // getHeight-returns height of patient

    double getWeight() const;
        // getWeight- returns weight of patient

    //Mutator Functions
    void setName(string);
        //set name of patient
        //@param string - name of patient

    void setRace(int);
        //setHeight-sets heigh tof patient
        //@param int- height iof patient

    void setWeight(double);
    //setWeight-sets weight of patiend
    //@param double-weight of patient



private:
    //Memeber variables
    string newName;
    int newRace;
    double newWeight;




};

#endif
```

and the second .cpp file

```
#include "HeroProfile.h"

eroProfile::HeroProfile() //Default constructor
{
newRace = 0;
newWeight = 0.0;
}

HeroProfile::HeroProfile(string name, int race, double weight) //Overloaded Constructor
{
newName = name;
newRace = race;
newWeight = weight;
}

HeroProfile::HeroProfile()
}
}

//Accessors
string HeroProfile::getName() const 
{
return newName;
}

int HeroProfile::getRace() const 
{
return newRace;
}

double HeroProfile::getWeight() const
{
return newWeight;
}

//Mutators
void HeroProfile::setName(string name)
{ 
newName = name;
}

void HeroProfile::setRace(int race)
{
newRace = race;
}


void HeroProfile::setWeight(double weight)
{
newWeight = weight;
}
```

Comment: You have two copies of `HeroProfile::HeroProfile()`. They're your first and third functions in the second .cpp file.

Comment: Use copy-paste instead of typing things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, you have 2 definitions in your second cpp file for the `HeroProfile` default constructor `HeroProfile::HeroProfile()`:

The first is

```
HeroProfile::HeroProfile() //Default constructor
{
newRace = 0;
newWeight = 0.0;
}
```

and the second is

```
HeroProfile::HeroProfile()
}
}
```

Based on the fact I don't see one, you probably intended for the second one to be your class destructor (as declared in your header file but not defined in your cpp file), in which case you should replace it with this:

```
HeroProfile::~HeroProfile()
}
}
```

I hope you didn't get confused by the fact that `HeroProfile::HeroProfile(void)` and `HeroProfile::HeroProfile()` are the same thing, so I thought I should point it out.

Answer (score 1):

The message means exactly what it says. Ignoring typos, the first and third definitions in your second .cpp are for the same function.